In a Cholesky SVAR, why does the main diagonal of the B matrix always have identical z-scores?
Look for example at the z statistics of the B matrix on page 8 here...
https://www.stata.com/manuals/tsvarsvar.pdf
...or on page 98 here...
https://www.eviews.com/StructVAR/structvar.pdf
...or at 10:58 here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSygD2SG_kM

reasonable question but seems like it will need someone with very specific expertise to answer it (without spending lots of time getting up to speed on the framework itself ...)
